# COUNTIF with Dates(Month)

Tags: excel, countif

I'm trying to count rows where the date in a Date column falls within a particular month. I've tried many paths but all result in an error in my formula. They boil down to me trying to do this:

```
=countIF(Month(SHData[@MS550]),MONTH(SHData[@MS550]))
```

My final formula will need to be more complex than that, but even something as simple as the above generates an error. I've also tried it with Text(Date,"MMMM") with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier with COUNTIFS but with COUNTIF you might count all the entries greater than or equal to the start of your chosen month, then subtract from that the count of all the entries after the end of your chosen month. Something like:

```
=COUNTIF(SHData[MS550],">42004")-COUNTIF(SHData[MS550],">42036")
```

for January this year, if using the 1900 date system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SumProduct, this just worked fine for me with a column of dates testing if they were in September:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(C3:C5>0),--(MONTH(C3:C5)=9))
```